# IOS App Distribution deploy In House failed Installation because of manifest.plist

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, deployment, manifest

I just publish an in-house app on IOS through Xcode for any device. 
In Xcode I go to Product/Archive/Distribute App --> I get a bunch of file and especially .ipa and manifest.plist .

It failed to install the App, the pop-up failed to install appear.
After some test, it was the manifest.plist, I change it and **now it work**.

My question is : **How to see logs of why installation failed** ? Or **how to test it before** ? When I use a provisionning profil for debug I can't detect these bug ...

I already have the IOS Console that print every log for the device, but I don't find the reason there.

Also sometime it doesn't try to install at all and just directly pop up the "Failed to install" sometime it appear at more thant 50% of installation.

Comment: Which provisioning profile you are using to distribute application? 
Try to delete previously installed build and install new build.

Comment: What change you did in manifest.plist?

Comment: In fact many thing was incorrect in the original Manifest.plist, it switch full-size image with software ipa url so it couldn't work

Comment: Be sure to remove any previous version. You can check installation Logs using the `Console` app

Comment: But my question is more about how could I see the problem come from manifest.plist or from the provisionning profile or other stuff. I found it by luck but the log from my ipad device don't tell me anything ...

Comment: @CZ54 I check all log in the console app from my device ... and nothing indicate me where come from the bug...
Even if I put a false url, it just say cannot install....

Comment: your manifest is served through https?

Comment: Not sure what do you mean, It's locate on a distant server and you access it via an url/index.php which point on this manifest.plist. There isn't certificate for this kind of url so it's not httpS.

Comment: For it, I think you need to use testflight to distribute your app. So, Apple can verify binary and share error code with description.

Comment: Hmm It might be an idea, I never use that ! Thanks